# How do I create and test IIS modules w/Visual Studio 2022 (within IISExpress)?

Tags: session-cookies, visual-studio-2022, iis-express, iis-modules

I'm trying to create a custom IIS module that deletes and/or alters session cookies sent from the browser to IIS and vice-versa, and would like to compile and test that module w/IISExpress (within VisualStudio 2022).

The module should be able to intercept HTTP requests from the browser, and delete (or modify) the session cookie it sends, as well as intercept the corresponding HTTP response from the web server, and delete (or modify) the "Set-Cookie" header it sends.  Further, the module should able to maintain its STATE (i. e. variable values) between individual HTTP requests/reponses.

Documentation from Microsoft on the creation and testing of IIS modules w/the lastest version of Visual Studio appears to be scant--all I could find was...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework

While it seems to offer an explanation of how to create modules, there's no explanation of whether the module can maintain its state between requests and also how to go about loading and testing it w/IISExpress.  Also the documentation appears to be dated--the version of Visual Studio featured there appears to be extra-old

So I'm wondering if someone can provide me w/sample code as to how this can be done, as well as the steps needed (including any alterations to the web.config file) to include this module so it can be tested w/IISExpress within Visual Studio, as well as the required location of the module (where it should be saved so IISExpress loads it).

Thanks

Comment: As most of the documents were created around 2008, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/develop-a-native-cc-module-for-iis, they got lost during several rounds of Microsoft documentation refreshes. If you are going to develop a native module, then the best example is [ASP.NET Core module](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/v7.0.5/src/Servers/IIS/AspNetCoreModuleV2).